# How to run Android test case without connecting device or emulator?

Tags: android, testing, junit, case

In android I am working on JUNIT test cases which are working fine on emulator and device, but I just want to know that how I can run test case in the absence of emulator and device.

Is their any way to execute android test cases without using emulator and device?

Any reference link or point of information will be help full for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I face some problem to implement this. In above link @ point 1 they specify android plugin version 1.1.0-rc1 and I have 1.2.1 also gradle version which I used is 2.4 I think it should work for me. but then point 6 & 7 is not work for me. and I am not able to run test case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the newest version of Android Studio, it should allow you to run the junits without the emulator or device, so long as those junits are not dependent on having the emulator/device running.

It is important to put the junit test files in the app/src/**test**/java/[apk_package]/ folder, not the app/src/**androidTest**/java/[apk_package]/ folder! Putting it in the androidTest folder will force run the android emulator or device runner.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Robolectric is designed for. In my limited use its quite good but be warned: they're in between major releases and accurate documentation is pretty sparse.

Comment: Thanks for your input it really help me to change my approach. And right now I am looking forward to used both Mockito and Robolectric together. If you have any idea about this then please let me know.